# Do you say two baskets of apples?

Tags: grammatical-number, questions

- Plural of basket is baskets.
- Plural of apple is apples.

Assuming there is more than one apple in each basket.

> There are two baskets of apples.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: What sentence?  The sentence “Is this sentence grammatically correct?” is correct, yes.  If you had another sentence in mind, you should place it in your question body clearly marked as such. Also, remember that English is not a mathematics equation, so using math reasoning seldom leads to a correct answer as applied to English.

Comment: Sorry, added the sentence now.

Comment: 'one basket of apple' = You have one basket, and in that one basket is some apple substance, maybe applesauce?

Comment: I believe this question would have fit better at the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange, which is designed for more basic English and grammar questions. You're welcome to participate in both communities, of course, but may want to consider asking questions like this one over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The container is pluralized, and the content retains whatever number it had in a single container. So:

- One basket of apple**s** ... two basket**s** of apple**s**
- One can of bean**s** ... two can**s** of bean**s**
- One crate of celery ... two crate**s** of celery

The same holds for forms:

- One wheel of cheese ... two wheel**s** of cheese
- One side of beef ... two side**s** of beef
- One bunch of grape**s** ... two bunch**es** of grape**s**

This is, however, a comparatively recent ‘rule’. In old texts, and in some present-day dialects, you may encounter *two keg of brandy*, *two loaf of bread*, *two pound of sugar*, *two barrel of pilchards*; and *two dozen eggs* (older often *two dozen **of** eggs*) and *two brace of grouse* are still standard.